# Expected value problem... Infinite series with factorial

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, convergence-divergence, expectation

In an exercise I have to calculate the following expected value:
$$
\sum_{i=4}^\infty500\frac{e^{-4}4^i}{i!}
$$
Leaving $500e^{-4}$ outside and using D'Alambert's criterion (with $a_n = \frac{4^n}{n!}$) we have:

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{4^{n+1}}{(n+1)n!}\frac{n!}{4^n}|=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{4}{n+1}|$

Thus we can say that the series converges, but now the problem is that I need to calculate the expected value, but I don't know how, because they have just taught me how to determine whether a series converges, but not how to get the value at which converges.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{i=4}^{\infty}500 e^{-4}\frac{4^i}{i!}=500 e^{-4}\sum_{i=4}^{\infty}\frac{4^i}{i!}=500 e^{-4}\Big(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^i}{i!}-\sum_{i=0}^{3}\frac{4^i}{i!}\Big)$$

Comment: You are welcome ! I suppose that you got the simple explicit result.

Comment: Curious.  A mathematician may quickly think $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^i}{i!} = e^4$ as the definition of the exponential function, but a statistician may be as fast thinking $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{-4}\frac{4^i}{i!} = 1$ from the probability mass function of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @Henry. May I confess that, up to the time your comment came, I was totally ignorant of what could be the meaning of *the probability mass function of a Poisson distribution*. Thanks for helping ! Cheers :-)